# How to get dimension of Logo and Crest

Tags: images, header-image

I want know width and height from (images)  Logo and Crest, current I use standard PHP function **[getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)** in my theme

```php
/**
 *  Get dimensions for image
 */
if (!function_exists('get_image_dimensions')) {
    function get_image_dimensions($url)
    {
        $size = getimagesize($url); 
        $width = $size[0];
        $height = $size[1];

        return array('width' => $width, 'height' => $height);
    }
}
```

Exist native function for it ?

Comment: Your function looks fine. Since PHP provides `getimagesize()`, there's no need for a WordPress function to duplicate it.

Comment: @PatJ but with this function site loading to be little bit slow in according with Lighthouse

Comment: If there *was* a WP function to do this, it would almost certainly use `getimagesize()` as well. If `getimagesize()` is slowing down your site, you might consider stashing its results in an option so you only need to run it once (assuming that your logo and crest don't change).